# Jquery take height of div, devide and add 5 px

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use a jquery to take 50% af a div height, and then add 5px to it. But i can't make it work. What i want it to do is a simple formel (Height/2) + 5 i'v managed to make the /2 work, but when i try adding the 5 px, it dosen't work.

Here is what i tried to do:

```
var KontaktForm = $("#KontaktForm").height();

$("#GMap").css({ ("height": KontaktForm / 2) + 5 'px ' });
```

This just dont work. I'm sure i am adding back the 5px wrong, but how i should do it otherwise, i can't figure out!

Comment: `{ height: ((KontaktForm / 2) + 5) +'px'}`  Your `()` are incorrectly placed around height giving it syntax errors.  Same thing with the trailing 'px ' missing a leading `+`

Comment: Taplar Ahhhh, makes sence, now that i see it too. Thanks alot!